# Why the data from my API is not displaying on my HTML page?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to display the data from my data base using API but it is not displaying on my Angular HTML component. I can see that the data is being fetch through the console and the HTML page is also reading how many items are in my table but the data like id, name, email, and etc is not being displayed and it just create the rows but the data is blank.

Here is what my html page looks like when I tried only fetching the id and input 1,2,3,4 for name, email, phone, and salary.

```
Id  Name    Email   Phone   Salary
        1       2       3       4
        1       2       3       4
        1       2       3       4
```

I can see this data in my Network Tab.

```
0 : {id: "30b3d36c-2747-4597-85df-1c187261d633", name: "test1", email: "test1@gmail.com",…}
1 : {id: "efaed07c-55ee-498c-b152-2d30c7dfad7b", name: "test2", email: "test2@gmail.com",…}
2 : {id: "503b1cf9-1948-4ca0-87ae-77a5680328f4", name: "test3", email: "test3@gmail.com",…}
```

Here is my code for the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/models/employee.model';
import { EmployeesService } from 'src/app/services/employees.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees-list',
  templateUrl: './employees-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesListComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Employee[] = [];
  constructor(private employeesService: EmployeesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeesService.getAllEmployees()
    .subscribe({
      next: (employees) => {
        this.employees = employees;
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Here is my code for the employees.services

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeesService {

  baseApiUrl: string = environment.baseApiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employee');
  }
}
```

Here is my component.html code.

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Employees</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
                <td>{{employee.Id}}</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- <p *ngIf="!employees || employees.length == 0">No Employees</p> -->
</div>
```

Here is my model code.

```
export interface Employee 
{
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: number;
    Salary: number;
    Department: string;
}
```

Comment: Include your html file for rendering the employee data. A useful debugging step is to stick a `<pre>{{ employees | json }}</pre>` in your html to see the data directly

Comment: I edited and added the html code. I also try using the <pre>{{ employees | json }} </pre> and I was able to see the raw form of the data in my html page.

Comment: should be {{ employee.id }} not {{ employee.Id }}

Comment: I tried that but I received an error because my model is on upper case. I will include the model in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your api data the properties are lowercase suggesting:

```
            <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
                <td>{{ employee.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
            </tr>
```

Given you've used typescript correctly this should be erroring and telling you this during `ng serve` unless your `Employee` type needs correcting to lowercase properties too?

Comment: My model variable name is Id, Name, Email, Phone, Salary. When I tried lower case, it throws me an error and the page is not loading at all.

Comment: To repeat, **your data from the api is lowercase**. So you’ll either have to map your data to the frontend model `.pipe(map(arr => arr.map(employee => ({ Id: employee.id, etc. }))))` or change your frontend model to reflect the backend

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I just tried editing my model and make it lower case and gosh, everything works. Haha. It so simple yet it took me almost 3 days hahaha. Thank you for your help.